# ngx-select-dropdown -- how to set default value for the dropdown? (angular 6.x)

Tags: angular, angular6

I looked at some of the similar questions but they are not answering my question correctly. here is my ngx-select-dropdown code in the template.

```
<ngx-select-dropdown [config]="{displayKey: 'name', search: true, placeholder: 'pick one'}"
                   [(value)]="selectedDatasource"
                   [options]="layoutSandbox.datasource$ | async"
                   [multiple]="false" (change)="onChangeDatasource($event)"> 
</ngx-select-dropdown>
```

As the array of object is coming dynamically, i need to select the "first" value of the array as the default option and accordingly, the rest of the data on the page will change.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an *async* pipe, you could subscribe to the dynamically loaded data from within the component and in the subscription block you can set the first element of the received  array to *selectedDataSource* object like shown below.

**Template**

```
<ngx-select-dropdown [config]="{displayKey: 'name', search: true, placeholder: 'pick one'}"
       [(value)]="selectedDatasource"
       [options]="layoutSandbox.datasource"
       [multiple]="false" (change)="onChangeDatasource($event)"> 
</ngx-select-dropdown>
```

**Component**

```
this.layoutSanbox.dataSource$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.layoutSandbox.dataSource = data;
      this.selectedDataSource = this.layoutSandbox.dataSource[0];
});
```

Comment: thanks. works except that the selectedDatasource is not updating :(
and that was the main goal!

Comment: Try `this.selectedDataSource = [this.layoutSandbox.dataSource[0]];` Since ngx-select-dropdown expects an array for value property. See [github](https://github.com/manishjanky/ngx-select-dropdown/blob/master/demo/src/app/app.component.ts) - singleSelect

Comment: binding with [(value)] didn't work for me, I used [(ngModel)]  instead

Answer (score 1):

Use ngModel instead of value

```
<ngx-select-dropdown [config]="{displayKey: 'name', search: true, placeholder: 'pick one'}"
                   [(ngModel)]="selectedDatasource"
                   [options]="layoutSandbox.datasource$ | async"
                   [multiple]="false" (change)="onChangeDatasource($event)"> 
</ngx-select-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try settings the first element of you array to **selectedDatasource**, and use **change output** in component to fire when the selected value is changes and act accordingly to that.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. This is what I am trying, but somehow, the selectedDatasource is not getting updated.

Comment: if is an array try this selectedDatasource = [...selectedDatasource]

Answer (score 0):

make sure you import FormsModule under the module imports. That's if it's template forms, which seems to the the case above